# Angular - pass data from uploaded file to other component

Tags: angular

I have one component (FileUploadComponent) that accepts a file as input and puts the data from the file into an array. After the file has been uploaded and data added to the array, I would like to pass this data to another component for use. I have been able to pass the FileUploadComponent to the other component and access its methods, but even though the array has data in FileUploadComponent, the other component sees it as an empty array.

I am open to suggestions for how to better implement this. Basically what I am trying to achieve is to allow a user to upload a list of names which would then be handled by the app. I have already achieved this with a service that takes the names from a built in .json file but I would like the user to be able to input the names. I realize that I am probably going about this messily so if there is another, simple way to achieve this then I am open to it.

Here is my code I am working with so far (clipped out irrelevant methods)

FileUploadComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  fileName = '';
  fileData: any;
  icon = 'attach_file'
  partners = []
  text = ''

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.fileData = event.target.files[0];

    if (this.fileData) {
      this.fileName = this.fileData.name;
      this.icon = 'check_circle'
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = (event) => {
        this.text = fileReader.result as string;
        console.log(fileReader.result);
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(this.fileData);
      
    }
    console.log(this.text)
  }

  confirmUpload() {
    for (const line of this.text.split(/[\r\n]+/)){
      this.partners.push(line);
    }
    console.log(this.partners);
  }

// The previous methods add the file data to partners[]. This method returns the data.
// I have tested within this component and it does return the data as intended.
  getData() {
    console.log(this.partners);
    return this.partners
  }

}
```

PartnersComponent - Component to receive data from FileUploadComponent

```
import { FileUploadComponent } from '../file-upload/file-upload.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-partners',
  templateUrl: './partners.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partners.component.css']
})
export class PartnersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private fileUploadComponent: FileUploadComponent ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

// Method is triggered on button click in template and returns empty array instead of data
  confirmData() {
    this.fileUploadComponent.getData();
  }

}
```

**Edit - Solution:**

Created a shared service to get and pass the variable between the two components like so. Setting an output property as suggested in the comments may also be viable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  partnerData: string[] = [];

  constructor() { 
    console.log("Initial Partner Data is: " + this.partnerData);
  }

  setPartnerData(val: string[] = []) {
    this.partnerData = val;
  }

  getPartnerData() {
    return this.partnerData;
  }
}
```

Comment: is both of this components used in the same html?

Comment: You can create a shared service between those two components. When you select the file in your FileUploadComponent, you save it in a variable inside your service. And when you need that file in your PartnersComponent, you fetch it from the service.

Comment: The FileUploadComponent is using its own html template (file-upload.component.html). Containing:

<input type="file" class="file-input"
       (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>

Comment: I mean, is both components you want to pass data between them, are in the same wrapper component?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick responses. I have accomplished this with the shared service as suggested and added it to the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an output property on the component upload and emit the new value to the parent component if the uploaded component is the child. Or use a shared service with a subject and subscribe to it.

Comment: Thank you! Following your advice and Leonardo's in the comments above, I created a shared service to pass the array variable from FileUploadComponent using a setter method, and then retrieve it in PartnersComponent with a getter method and it worked!